# Displaying webpage on a iphone 4/4s

Tags: iphone, html, css, media-queries, viewport

I have a webpage which I have created a media query for a resolution of 480px in width.

The iphone 4 correctly picks up this version but for some reason it overhangs the page its not using the actual resolution of the iphone 4 which is 640px in width its using a width of 320px. (i read somewhere that it does this for backward compatibility with apps developed for iphone 3)

Is there a way using a viewport or a media query to correct this? Or does someone have an example of how to implement an iphone media query, ive tried this with no luck.

Is there a way to stretch the 480px media query to fit the iphone?

This is my current viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1; maximum-scale=5.0; minimum-scale=0.5;" />
```

Media query - this does nothing and ive tried with just `-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2` only

```
@media screen  and (max-width: 480px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

This media query in css3 should detect any iphone or ipod

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px), only screen and (min-device-width: 640px) and (max-device-width: 1136px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
```

The way I understand it is that retina screens will still act as if they are the normal old screens. you act as if things are still 320px is the width. if you want something to take up the full width of an iphone in portrait then you would use 320px not 640px. Really you should be using percentages and ems though not exact px sizes.

Not sure if this answered anything, but I think you were wanting to know why if you set something to 640px it would hang off the edge and not just take up the width of the retina screen.